# Get HTTP status code from AWS API Gateway Android SDK

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to use the AWS generated Android SDK for my API Gateway project. Based on the information on this [Site](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-android.html) I created a client interface with a API method like this:

```js
@com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.annotation.Operation(path = "/events/bookingUpdate", method = "POST")
void bookingUpdatePost(BookingUpdate body);
```

So when I want to call my API I used the following code:

```js
 try {
    clientInterface.bookingUpdatePost(generateBookingUpdateDeviceInformation(bookingUpdate));
} catch (ApiClientException e) {
    Log.e(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onBookingUpdatePostRequestFinished(new Error(e.getLocalizedMessage()));
    }
}
```

is there any way to retrieve the APIResponse Headers from the amazon mobile connectors library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to do so because it's not exposed externally.  But you can use a generic invoker instead to achieve this.

Comment: okay, thanks! than I probably move on with an own solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

`ApiClientException` will contain non 2** status codes which can be retrieved by calling `e.getStatusCode()`. Otherwise I don't see a way to get headers unless you call the `ApiResponse execute(ApiRequest request);` method directly to get a reference to the `ApiResponse` instance.

For references, here's the source code for the `handleResponse`:

```
    /**
     * Converts response to method's declared returned object
     *
     * @param response http response
     * @param method method
     * @return object of method's declared returned type
     * @throws Throwable
     */
    Object handleResponse(HttpResponse response, Method method) throws Throwable {
        final int code = response.getStatusCode();
        final InputStream content = response.getContent();
        // successful request if code is 2xx
        if (code >= HTTP_RESPONSE_OK && code < HTTP_RESPONSE_LAST_SUCCESS_STATUSCODE) {
            final Type t = method.getReturnType();
            if (t != void.class && content != null) {
                final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(response.getContent(),
                        StringUtils.UTF8);
                final Object obj = GSON_WITH_DATE_FORMATTER.fromJson(reader, t);
                reader.close();
                return obj;
            } else {
                // discard response
                if (content != null) {
                    content.close();
                }
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            final String error = content == null ? "" : IOUtils.toString(content);
            final ApiClientException ase = new ApiClientException(error);
            ase.setStatusCode(response.getStatusCode());
            ase.setServiceName(apiName);
            final String requestId = response.getHeaders().get("x-amzn-RequestId");
            if (requestId != null) {
                ase.setRequestId(requestId);
            }
            throw ase;
        }
    }
```